# Is there a way with rails form helper to produce a button tag for submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, custom-tag

I am trying to create buttons ala Wufoo ([Rediscovering the button element](http://particletree.com/features/rediscovering-the-button-element/))

I would like to write the following code like the following:

```
<%form_tag search_path, :method => :get, :class => 'search' do %>
  <%=text_field_tag :search, params[:search] -%>
  <%=button_tag 'search', :name => nil-%>
<%end%>
```

To generate the following HTML (instead of the input[type="submit"] tag)

```
<button type="submit" class="positive">
    <img src="/images/icons/tick.png" alt=""/> 
    Save
</button>
```

Does a method exist already?  Or should I roll my own helper?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could use content_tag to achieve this. It's the more railsy way of doing what you want. But it's longer than the raw HTML.

```
<% content_tag :button :type => :submit, :class => :positive do %>
   <%= image_tag "icons/tick.png"%>
   Save
<% end %>
```

Which produces

```
<button type="submit" class="positive">
    <img src="/images/icons/tick.png" alt="Tick"/> 
    Save
</button>
```

However using this as a starting point you should have no problem rolling your own robust helper, or abstracting it to a partial.

Comment: How would a helper make this faster?

Comment: @TheExit: A helper would not make it faster. I never claimed it would, in fact the content tag would be slower than just inputting the raw html as a string. But the helper lends itself to easy reuse, which makes it faster in terms of time spent writing code on future uses of this kind of button.

Comment: I made a helper called "button_tag" and it behaves exactly as all the other rails form helper methods and as such it makes me happy.

Comment: to get "update" or "create" text you can do t("helpers.submit.#{@your_model.persisted? ? 'update' : 'create' }"

Comment: This is probably very late and nobody even cares.. but you forgot the "=" before the content_tag :)

Comment: This is probably also very late and nobody even cares..but for me a "," after the :button is needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [image_submit_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M001740) helper to create an image submit tag, rather than wrapping the whole thing in a button:

```
<%
image_submit_tag("login.png")
# => <input src="/images/login.png" type="image" />

image_submit_tag("purchase.png", :disabled => true)
# => <input disabled="disabled" src="/images/purchase.png" type="image" />

image_submit_tag("search.png", :class => 'search-button')
# => <input class="search-button" src="/images/search.png" type="image" />
%>
```

This might not be what you're looking for, if you require the "Save" text to appear above the `<img>`

Answer (score 0):

Use The JQuery Cheats Gem https://github.com/plowdawg/jquery_cheats and in your view it is just

```
<%= submitimage("/path/to/image.png","Alternate Text") %>
```

**NOTE:** Alternate text is optional.