# rails create a button for downloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to create a button for downloading 
So far I have create a button using this

> <%= form_tag '/myproject/download',
>   :multipart => true,
>   :onclick=>"document.getElementById('popup').style.display='block';
>   return true;" %>
>           <%= submit_tag 'Download'%>
>         <% end %>

but I don"t know how to link the submit_tag with the link of downloading. (so as simple as if I press the button, then it will go to localhost/file and pop up a save to option)
I am aware that I can use link_to, but I need to put a button that acts as a link_to

Can anyone point out how to do this in rails? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `button_to` method, which is nearly identical to `link_to`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

Answer (score 0):

You can put a link_to and then style it like a button. Or you can do something like this [Is there a way with rails form helper to produce a button tag for submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254720/is-there-a-way-with-rails-form-helper-to-produce-a-button-tag-for-submit)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the **button_to** method. You can take a look to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to).