# button with an image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a button with an image. So basically, I need the button_to version of the code below :|

```
<%= link_to image_tag(product.image_url, :class => "img"), line_items_path(:product_id => product) %>
```

Comment: Please explain what is the problem and give information about the error you got

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty old post, but for future reference: since Rails 3.2.1 you can use `button_tag` instead of `button_to`, as the first one natively allows images:

> Creates a button element that defines a submit button, reset button or a generic button which can be used in JavaScript, for example. You can use the button tag as a regular submit tag but it isn’t supported in legacy browsers. However, the button tag allows richer labels such as images and emphasis, so this helper will also accept a block.

As for your example:

```
<%= button_tag image_tag(product.image_url), line_items_path(:product_id => product), class: 'img' %>
```

I didn't test the code, but it should work. It is possible you need to declare the url with `url:`

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

Use a button helper (you can use the button_to helper method):

```
<%= f.submit 'Save', :class => "button_with_image_save" %>
```

CSS:

```
.button_with_image_save {
    background: url(../images/icons/page_save.png) #f2efa8 no-repeat 10px 6px;
    text-indent:30px;
    display:block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Image submit button:

```
<%= image_submit_tag("team/team1.png", class: 'image-responsive') %>
```

Link with image:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("team/team1.png", class: 'image-responsive'), root_path,  :method => :get) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper as button_to link -

```
<%= button_to product.image_url, line_items_path(:product_id => product) %>
```

and in application_helper

```
def button_to(image_path, link)
  link_to (image_tag(image_path, :class => "img"), link)
end
```

I guess this is what you want.

Comment: this one creates link, not a button. im suggest to create button and style it via css

Comment: A button can only be used to submit or reset forms. If you just want looks, then you can style <a> tag to look that way.

Comment: Is that last comment accurate? I've attached non-submit behavior to button tags quite often...

Comment: @jaydel yes, but then that will be something you will do with javascripts and not with basic functions of button tag. see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you need to create a helper method, which is quite simple to do:

Here is a similar SO posting the explains it: [Is there a way with rails form helper to produce a button tag for submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254720/is-there-a-way-with-rails-form-helper-to-produce-a-button-tag-for-submit/2255049#2255049)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Add the image is the folder **app/assets/image**

In the view

```
<%= image_submit_tag('nameimage.png') %>
```

the disadvantage is that you can not change the size with size, but you must have the image of the size you want to appear