# Embedded HTML in button tag rails button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way with rails form helper to produce a button tag for submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254720/is-there-a-way-with-rails-form-helper-to-produce-a-button-tag-for-submit)

This is probably quite an easy question, but I've got this HTML layout:

```
<button class="btn btn-large btn-inverse"><i class="icon-white icon-shopping-cart"></i> Add to bag</button>
```

This is an add to cart button, I'm following along the book Agile Web Development to create a cart. Question is, with embedded HTML between the button tag, how do I get it to render like that? I tried this:

```
%= button_to raw('<i class="icon-white icon-shopping-cart"></i> Add to bag'), line_items_path(product_id: product) %>
```

But firstly it prints an "input" not a button, and the text is all askew in the html and not between opening and closing tags.

I know I can just write it all manually, but was hoping to figure out if there's a shortcut way to do this HTML to output using the rails tags, mainly because with twitter bootstrap I see this type of HTML pattern all the time...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ok I check content tag, and have this: <%= content_tag(:button, :class => 'btn btn-large btn-inverse') do %>
            <%= content_tag :i, '', :class => 'icon-white icon-shopping-cart' %> Add to bag
        <% end -%>   --- but how to now create the form easily?

Comment: Well that's a different question, but you have to wrap it in a form that submits to `line_items_path(product_id: product)` and then in your `content_tag` you have to set `:type => submit`.

Comment: you can add creating a form into a helper method as well, just wrap content_tag in a `form_for .. do ... end` or `form_tag .. do ... end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Mischa, it is similar to [Is there a way with rails form helper to produce a button tag for submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254720/is-there-a-way-with-rails-form-helper-to-produce-a-button-tag-for-submit).

The content_tag helper can be used to write the button in rails. However, it is not a shortcut, since it will take longer to write than the raw html.

However, if you need to do this often, you can write a custom helper method to do it the way you want!

Just add to your app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
def my_button_to name, options = {}, html_options = {} # or some variation
  # eg. deal with options hash the way button_to deals with it here?
  content_tag :button, html_options = nil do
    raw name
  end
end
```

---

Now you can use this in your views:

```
<%= my_button_to '<i class="icon-white icon-shopping-cart"></i> Add to bag', {}, :class => "btn btn-large btn-inverse" %>
```

Comment: This is a bad idea, because Rails already has a `button_to` helper that works differently. You'd better use a different name for this button helper.

Comment: @Mischa, ok fine, changed the name

Comment: ok ta, I think I'll just use the form_tag wrapper around the content tags, this seems straightforward. Thanks folks.