# how to change html of submit button in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I submit form then I write <% f.submit %> and it's html like `<input id="subscriptions" name="commit" type="submit" value="Save">` but I want this `<button class="btn submit" type="button">SUBMIT</button>`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= f.submit id: nil, name: nil, value: nil, class: "btn submit" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ref [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254720/is-there-a-way-with-rails-form-helper-to-produce-a-button-tag-for-submit)

```
<% content_tag :button :type => :submit, :class => "btn submit" do %>
<% end %>
```